# Sidecar and Microsoft OneNote

Tags: macos, catalina, onenote, apple-pencil, sidecar

I am a little bit confused. I want to use an iPad with Sidecar and OneNote on a MacBook Pro. Everything is working fine, but if I select "Text mode" under drawing, I am not able to control my cursor with the Apple Pencil, instead the pencil is drawing lines which can only be erased by selecting a pen under "Draw" in OneNote.

I simply need to control the cursor with the Apple Pencil. Is that possible?